# Laravel customized subscription updating subscribed_at for all the update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

I am using a customized subscription which is not laravel's default cashier.
and the migration looks as below

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->bigInteger('plan_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('subscription_plans');
        $table->bigInteger('transaction_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('transaction_id')->references('id')->on('transactions');
        $table->timestamp('subscribed_at');
        $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
        $table->json('benefits');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and the user relation as below

```
// subscription
public function subscriptions(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class, 'user_id')->orderBy('subscribed_at', 'asc');
}
```

on a specific case, I update the `is_active` flag.

```
// in user model : User.php
public function createSubscription(Plan $plan): Subscription
{   
    $transaction = $this->createTransaction($plan);
    $data = [
        'plan_id' => $plan->id,
        'transaction_id' => $transaction->id,
        'is_active' => true,
        'subscribed_at' => now(),
        'expires_at' => now()->addDays($plan->validity),
        'is_active' => true,
        'benefits' => $plan->benefits
    ];
    $this->subscriptions()->update(['is_active' => false]);
    return $this->subscriptions()->create($data);
}
```

but it's updating all the `subscribed_at` timestamps.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you please post related code in User.php ?

Comment: Have updated @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the **subscribed_at** column type from ***timestamp*** to ***dateTime*** (Or make it nullable())

Like:

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {

    // ...       
    
    $table->dateTime('subscribed_at');
    
    // ...

});
```

Comment: timestamp with nullable works Shabeer, Thanks!